# Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel 2010 Bubble Chart Gradients

Tags: excel, ms-office, com-interop, office-interop

I am trying to set some properties of charts created programatically, but am unable to set the property *normally* found within Excel 2010 for a Bubble Chart at:

> Format Data Series | Fill | Gradient Fill | Type | **Radial**

using the code below.

```cs
Interop.Series s = TemplateBubble.SeriesCollection(1);
Interop.ChartFillFormat ff = s.Fill;
ff.TwoColorGradient(Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoGradientStyle.msoGradientFromCenter, 2);
```

[ChartFillFormat.TwoColorGradient Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.chartfillformat.twocolorgradient.aspx) indicates the second parameter may set the type to Radial since there are 4 gradient types.

Upon debugging `ff.GradientVariant` is equal to `1` following the last line in the code displayed.  How do I get radial gradients?